# I want to make a sell script to input text into a command in debian

Tags: bash, shell

I am sorry if I am having trouble explaining, here is my issue,

I want to make a basic shell bash script say x.sh and I want to run command

change
htpasswd -b -c /etc/squid/squid_passwd root pass

Where the bash script will ask input username: and I type here xyz and hit enter

Then bash will ask input password: and I type here abc and hit enter

And shell will put xyz and abc in place of root:pass in the following command and run itself

change
htpasswd -b -c /etc/squid/squid_passwd root pass

And then input command,

Service squid restart

Can anybody help on how to do this?
Tried. Searching but unable to find the answer.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter name " name 
echo "Hi, $name"
read -sp "Enter password " pass
echo
echo "$name has provided the password $pass"
echo
change htpasswd -b -c
/etc/squid/squid_passwd $name $pass
Service squid restart
```

Something like this. The trick is put the password in a variable(basic programming) and then use that variable

Comment: I want the name to be the username instead of root and pass to be the pass what will be the example be like and to restart do I do echo service squid restart or just service squid restart

Comment: Change  root to `$name`